# create instance with dynamic columns for a model in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to create an instance of a model, but i have the fields in a dictionary, when the keys are field name and the values are field value.

I found a link that helped me for filtering, but I want to know how can i do to e instance. When i tried it for create, it showed me the following error:

create takes exactly 1 argument(2 given)

```
q = Q()
for k,v in dict.iteritems():
    q &= Q(**{'%s' % k: v})

if not model_class.objects.filter(q).exists():
    a = model_class.objects.create(q)
```

Any helps will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dict` with argument unpacking syntax:

```
if not model_class.objects.filter(**dict).exists():
    a = model_class.objects.create(**dict)
```

OR

```
a, created = model_class.objects.get_or_create(**dict)
```

BTW, don't use `dict` as variable name. It shadows builtin function [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict).